# About CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost of IOS

Tags: ios4, ios-4.2

What I am trying to do is to create 2 sockets to a Hostname and a Port. One connection is linked to input and output streams. One connection is linked to output stream only.

The first connection is created first with CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost and the corresponding streams are opened, then second connection is created with readstream as nil.

I found that I can send data to remote server via the two output streams. But iPhone cannot receive data from remote server.

p.s. If only first connection is made, it is no problem to send and receive data from server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you have to try different ports..